# Некорректная работа шрифтов CSS

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Мне надо, что бы в input был шрифт как на калькуляторе. Я его подключаю в CSS с именем Calc-Font, но, когда я ставлю этот шрифт (с таким именем), то он не работает, но, если название поменять, все работает.
Это единственный подключенный шрифт на странице.

Так оно работает:

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calc-Font';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url(../../lib/fonts/calcus.woff2) format('woff2');
}
#display {
  height: 58px;
  width: 422px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Calculator";
  font-size: 27px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="display-block"><input type="text" id="display"></div>
```

А если написать в #display 'Calc-Font' то работать не будет

Comment: ну так не пиши calc-font

Comment: @VladGavriuk Это не имеет значения, когда названия разные, все хорошо, шрифт работает. Но если названия одинаковые, то шрифт не работает...

Comment: Как в font-face его назвали, так и используйте, у вас в инпут подключается неизвестный шрифт

Comment: @ArtemGarlachev Он так не работает, я и хочу понять почему

Comment: @SonyaFreis Видимо конфликт стилей, попробуйте поменять названия одного из них..

Comment: @HedenShepard Поменять названия шрифта? Или таблицы стилей?

Comment: @HedenShepard Названия шрифтов менял не помогает

Comment: @SonyaFreis попробуйте поменять название таблицы стилей

Comment: @HedenShepard она единственная

Comment: Алё.. А почему в font-face `font-family: 'Calc-Font';`, а в стиле `font-family: "Calculator";`, всегда указывал так, как font-face и шрифты работали.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 В том то и проблема, когда я указываю их одинаково, он не работает... А если названия разные, то все гуд

Comment: @SonyaFreis Так оставьте разные названия  :)

Answer (score 0):

момент первый - проверить верен ли путь к файлу шрифта и второй момент - селектору #display добавьте font-weight:bold; и font-family: 'Calc-Font';